# Hosting IIS site on local company Network

Tags: wcf, iis, hosting

There are 3 people working on a project, one of which is working on a wcf service, is it possible for him to create an IIS site on his machine locally to host the service and allow the other members to access that service/site on his machine if we are on our company shared Network? I'm trying to see whats the best way to host this service on a test server so the other members can test it out as well without any bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes, that's the most common way of hosting WCF service.
Under project properties of your WCF service just select "Web" and then "Use local IIS server"

Comment: Right but they still can't access that local url if i gave it to them. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Couple things to check: 1) see if you can navigate to it locally - then you can verify if ASP.NET is registered with IIS 2) see if sample website with some static htm page can be hit remotely - maybe it is a network issue?

Comment: Well, you would use IP address or a symbolic name of the host, as a part of the URL so that would not be a local URL anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: yes, this is possible.  I have performed this exact setup by hosting a web site on a local laptop.  We have been able to access the site from dozens of computers on the same network successfully.